How To Control Object Type When Importing Large File From S3 To DynamoDB
I have a csv sitting in an S3 Bucket about 900,000 rows long, and within that csv I have two columns phone and ttl.
I am able to successfully import this csv into a new DynamoDB table, however I am NOT able to classify what type of object each column should be (which in the case of the ttl column that is classified as a string rather than number).
In the csv file itself the ttl values are not surrounded by quotation marks--just purely a number that's being misinterpreted.

How are you performing the import?

When using the import from S3 feature, you can only specify the types of the partition key and sort key attributes. All other attributes default to string.
As a workaround, you could convert the CSV objects into DDB-JSON or Ion. These data types support non-string types and can be used as a source format for an import.

If the table is only two keys as described above, could I have my sort key also be my ttl value?

Unfortunately while using CSV files and DynamoDB's import from S3 feature it imports non-key attributes as string type:

When importing from CSV files, all columns other than the hash range and keys of your base table and secondary indexes are imported as DynamoDB strings.

Src
It's best to convert the data to DDB-JSON first so it maintains its correctness. Depending on how much data you have you can either use

AWS Glue (large data)
AWS Lambda (small data)

When doing this, it's useful to leverage some of the SDKs serialisation libraries, such as pythons:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/_modules/boto3/dynamodb/types.html
The python one is super useful as you can use it in both Lambda and Spark.
from boto3.dynamodb.types import TypeDeserializer, TypeSerializer

item_to_store = {
    'user_id': '12345',
    'first_name': 'Terry',
    'age': 48,
}

serializer = TypeSerializer()

serialized_item = serializer.serialize(item_to_store)


I know we have different different definitions of large and small data haha. I'm looking to import ~900,000 rows, which isn't huge but also isn't so small that a lambda function could do it within, say, 20 minutes. I'm not well-versed in Python so I'd have to look for a nodejs example.

Lambda has a max runtime of 15 mins so it it takes longer than that use Glue or EC2 etc... You can reference the nodeJS Marshall/unmarshall from this blog post: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/exploring-amazon-dynamodb-sdk-clients/
